# I want to add search functionality to my App

Tags: android, database, search

Hello there developers.

I have a special Problem. I wrote an App for personal use. To learn coding for Android. I am not the most professional Programmer around here. The App consists of nearly 300 activities. Now I want to implement a search function. I want to enter a keyword and the App has to open the appropriate Activity.The amount of keywords are closed. I do not want to be able to add keywords. I simply want to search for the ones which there are. On user side. I can add them if I need more keywords. But for the first the keywords will be fix.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can provide which type of database your using ?

Comment: I am not using a DB. I read about using a DB but do not even know to do that. Like I said, I am a total newbie in coding.

Comment: Your search functionality needs any database or Array to search from it. So provide your database so we can help.

Comment: You can use Firebase or Api to store the data online. Or if your data is offline for limited user then you can use sqlite or room

Comment: Do you have some tutorial for that. I want to store the data in the App. The App has to work whether it is Online or Offline. Can Firebase do that?

Comment: Firebase can help you for something like this. You can use [realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)

Comment: I suggest to delete the question you got the documentation link. Your question incomplete so it can be put to hold

Comment: 300 activities? If each activities actually using same layout and logic but different "texts", you might doing it wrong. Patching 3 activities already painfull

Comment: They are indeed using the same logic and Layout. Only the content (text) is different. How can I make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

First You need to get the All activity that are in your app using this code

```
public ActivityInfo[] getActivityList() throws NameNotFoundException {
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext.getPackageName(), 
PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
ActivityInfo[] list = info.activities;
return list;
```

}

after that you need to start activity by that string name

```
String activityToStart = "com.example.MainActivity";
try {
Class<?> c = Class.forName(activityToStart);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
}
```

I know the code is incomplete but the process is same. You are welcome.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "incomplete"? What is missing?

Comment: It means you have to write your own code based on these syntax and logic to make it work.